# Can't align text correctly - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="page-header"><h3>Your Profile</h3></div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-right">Name:<br><br>Email:<br><br>Phone:<br><br>Gender:</div>
            <div class="col-md-8 text-left">John Smith<br><br>email@email.com<br><br>07878787456<br><br>Male</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-right">Name:<br><br>Email:<br><br>Phone:<br><br>Gender:</div>
            <div class="col-md-8 text-left">John Smith<br><br>email@email.com<br><br>07878787456<br><br>Male</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason it displays like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiqR1.png

Here is a jsfiddle (expand the size of the output box): http://jsfiddle.net/z49Ry/

The text with "Name:" etc should be aligned right, and the other text should be aligned left. For some reason the "Name:" etc does not align right properly on the left.

I'm guessing this is because maybe the span is too small, if so then what would be a better solution for displaying data?

Comment: Could probably be the line-height.

Answer (score 0):

I really can't figure out any errors in your code. Like you said it's probably caused by too thin column.

Using BR to separate data is probably worst approach. For tabular data use table. If tables isn't what you're looking for you can as well use unordered list or description list (DL).